# Android - Scandit Barcode Scanner issues with EAN-13

Tags: android, barcode, google-glass, barcode-scanner, ean-13

I implemented the scandit library in my google glass project, but if I'm scanning EAN-13 barcodes the last digit is always wrong. 
For example: I'm scanning a code with the value 2220141633626 and the result is 2220141633624.

This is my code in Activity 1:

```
public void didScanBarcode(String content, String format) {
    // send the result to another activity.
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TestingActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("scanContent", content);
    Log.v("scanbarcode", content);
    startActivity(resultIntent);
}
```

This is my code in Activity 2:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.testing);

    Intent resultIntent = getIntent();
    String scanContent = resultIntent.getExtras().getString("scanContent");
    serialNumber = Long.parseLong(scanContent);
    Log.e("string ", "" + scanContent);
    Log.e("long ", "" + serialNumber);

}
```

The content is already wrong in the didScanBarcode method of my first activity.

Answer (score 2):

`2220141633626` is not a valid EAN-13 code, while `2220141633624` is.

The first 12 numbers are the actual number, while the 13th is the 'check digit'. The check digit of `222014163362` is `4`.

See for example http://www.morovia.com/education/utility/upc-ean.asp, enter `222014163362` in the ean-13 field and press 'calculate'